# How do I correctly decode TCP packet data using the FIX protocol sniffed with scapy?

Tags: python, tcp, decode, scapy, fix-protocol

I am attempting to intercept the news traffic that comes into IBKR's Trader Workstation, it appears the news headlines are transmitted using the FIX protocol over TCP on port 4000. I am using scapy to sniff the packets and am having trouble correctly decoding the data into a fully readable format as it appears in the software.

Using the following line to attempt to decode the payload:

```
data = bytes(pkt[TCP].payload).decode('ascii','replace')
print(data)
```

I receive the following in console:

> 8=O9=020435=G?x??DJ-RTG?DJ-RTG$2715ba5?cM@u{A:8T0015:L:en}Press Release: Olink strengthens management team for cont$nued leadership in the modern pro?eomics era+!?8349=A15E2099

As you can see the string is slightly mangled with incorrectly decoded characters. The correct standalone headline less the protocol information should be:

> Press Release: Olink strengthens management team for continued leadership in the modern proteomics era

And when printing the payload alone I receive:

> b'8=O\x019=0204\x0135=G\x01\x05\xb0\x00\x00x\xf8\x00\xb0\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x06\x00\x06DJ-RTG\x00\x00\xf1\x00\x00\x0fDJ-RTG$\x1a2715ba5\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcc\x00\x00\x00\x00c\x0fM@\x00\x00\x00u{A:8T0015:L:en}Press Release: Olink strengthens management team for cont$nued leadership in the modern pro\xe0eomics era\x00\x00\x00\x05+!\xf5\x018349=A15E2099\x01'

I am very inexperienced in this area so I would appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

Comment: Do you have a link to the definition of the FIX protocol?  Decoding the entire packet as ASCII is incorrect.

Comment: I found some information here: https://labs.withsecure.com/blog/a-bit-of-a-fixer-upper-playing-with-the-fix-tcp-protocol/ However the message I'm receiving seems a bit different. It was better processed in Wireshark but there were also still some character errors.

Comment: This is no valid FIX message per the standard. In your output it starts with `8=O` where it should actually start with something like `FIX.4.4`. Maybe someone is misusing the FIX protocol for something other? https://www.fixtrading.org/standards/tagvalue-online/#standard-header-and-trailer

Comment: That's definitely possible. I don't think FIX is intended to be used for this kind of data. Although Wireshark identifies it as FIX protocol and is able to parse it to some extent but it does seem malformed.

Comment: The `\x01` notation used in the final output appears to denote ASCII character 1, which is used as a field delimiter in FIX. However, as Christoph John indicated, `8=0\x01` is incorrect; a FIX message should start with something like `8=FIX.4.4\x01` (perhaps with a different protocol version). By the way, the final field in a FIX message should have tag 10 (denoting the Checksum field) and the value after the `=` will be a 3-digit number. For example, `10=125\x01`. I mention that because a FIX message might be long enough to span several TCP packets.